# How to iterate over two lists of same size and setting the other list values in another list by iterating both the list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8

I have two lists from same table separated by `plan_by` column:

debit_transaction_table

```
     id     cust_id    amount      effective_date       plan_by
     1       1001      30000       2020-11-15           customer
     2       1001      40000       2020-11-16           Manager
     3       1002      10000       2020-09-08           Customer
     4       1002      30000       2020-10-11           Manager
```

I am querying the two table using hibernate criteria and getting list based on `cust_id` and `plan_by` column

- `managerList` : contains manager row
- `customerList` : contains customer row

Now I want to copy the managerList data and into customerList and save it into database.

My code is :

```
    managerList .forEach(mgr-> {
            customerList 
            .stream()
            .filter(cust-> cust.getCustomer().getCustId().equals(mgr.getCustomer().getCustId()))
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(cust-> cust.setId(mgr.getId()));
        });
```

Like this I want to set all the other fields like cust_id, amount, effectiveDate. How can I do it. Could you please help me here.

Comment: What would be the point in setting `cust_id`. given that you mapped the data on `cust_id`, i.e. the value is by nature already the same? --- What is the problem with the code you have (other than poor performance from the sequential search)? Please edit the question and clarify what it is that you need to be different. While you are at it, please clarify why you only show one list, when you say you have two lists.

Comment: Why do this in Java and not with SQL directly?

Comment: Please clarify what is the actual problem that you are facing. Also in the 1st line you have stated that "I have two lists from same table" then in next few lines you stated that "I am querying the two table using hibernate criteria". Do you mean 2 queries but from same table ?  Both lists contains same type of object ?